# Export selected cells to individual .txt files

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet, and I am trying to export a column of cells (Column H, titled "Agreement Text") to individual .txt files.

I am also trying to title each .txt file with text from a corresponding cell in another column (Column D, titled "File Name").

I'm trying to export the files to the following Mac file address:

/Users/mack/Desktop/Year\ 3/Dissertation/Cookie\ Agreement\ Corpus/Cookie\ Agreements\ Text\ Files

I have no experience with VBA, so any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
Dim c           As Range
Dim p           As String
Dim s           As String
Dim f           As Integer

p = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator  'Change Path To Suit

For Each c In Sheet1.Range("H2:H" & Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row)
    f = FreeFile()
    Open p & c.Offset(, -4) & ".txt" For Output As #f
    Print #f, c.Value
    Close #f
Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this! With "Change Path to Suit", what am I actually changing? Really sorry for being so clueless.

Comment: A path is usually the disc address where files are or are to be located